# Spring - UTF-8 characters in object hydrated from forms

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using `Spring` to retrieve validated object from my form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doCreate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreate(Model model, @Valid Offer offer, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println(offer.getName());

}
```

The problem is that `offer` doesn't contain proper `utf-8` characters within it.

For example, having `żółć` entered in field corresponding to `offer.name`, I end up with `&#380;ó&#322;&#263;` running above code.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't actually inserting `&#380;ó&#322;&#263;`; I don't know any JDBC driver that would convert to html entities. It sooner looks like this is what you actually try to insert. You might want to check if some form of encoding happens before your insert.

Comment: Good point, gonna check it when I get back home! Thanks

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've checked and you're right. Updated the question.

Comment: Which browser and which web container do you use?

Comment: Chrome 37, Tomcat 7. Happens also inside Eclipse built-in browser.